# Access the data from two observables without multiple subscriptions

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

My first observable emits data concerning my user (from Firebase). On this data being emitted, I'd like to trigger a second call to Firebase, retrieving various extra user information from a distinct collection.

I can manage the two operations individually just fine, but obviously the latter call should only really take place after the first call has succeeded. I imagine this is something to do with `mergeMap` but I can't figure out quite how to do it. Should point out to the close/downvoter that I've, despite trying, not found similar questions that are both answered and present the solution in a way I can match to exactly what I'm failing to understand.

```
this._auth.userState$
    .mergeMap(user => this._userMetaData.getData(user.uid))
    .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
    });
```

This is my initial effort. I was hoping that the console.log would return (in some fashion) the data from both calls. It just logs an empty array, instead.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see 2 different points worth to be highlighted.

1) Within the submit, you want to access the data returned by the 2 calls:

This can be accomplished in the following way

`.mergeMap(user => 
    this._userMetaData.getData(user.uid)
    .map(data => ({user, data})
 )`

Here you basically create, via the last `map`, a return which is an object referencing both the user returned by the first call and the data returned by the second call

2) In the log you see an empty Array:

Here you need to look at your logic since, according to your current code, in the log you should see the result of the second call

Comment: Thank you, that's got me to where I needed!